# overriding body/html class only on front page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site bringing in some full page slider functionality on my index.php. To work it sets the css to be

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

but I want my interior pages to overflow: auto;

I have two header.php files set up (one for interior pages one for index.php) with header-int.php set with the following

html

```
<body <?php body_class('auto'); ?> > ...
```

css

```
.auto { overflow: auto; }
```

Problem is I need to override the html css to be auto as well, not sure how to do that. OR have the html, body css target only the index.php and not any other page.

Comment: Maybe using the bad practices but hero value: !important ?

Comment: Ok, Instead of setting a class, set an ID that should override the preset CSS

Comment: Can you modify the HTML elements? Sorry, if this is an obvious question, I dont have to much experience when it comes to wordpress.

Comment: First of all, you should not need two separate header files for this – WP has functions such as `is_home` and `is_front_page` to determine what “page” you are currently on within a template. And then if your slider needs some special styles – create a class for that, and add it to body only on the page you want.

Comment: I don't know how I could set a style to the html tag in html

Answer (score 1):

I would revisit your header files here. There's plenty of functions that Wordpress provide which resolve this type of issue. I would add the following function to your header file: `is_front_page()`. More info on this here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>
  <body class="homepagebodyclass">
<?php } else { ?>
  <body class="auto">
<?php } ?>
```

Doing the above would remove the need to have more than one header file...

Comment: So i replace the simple <body> with this?

Comment: also I need this to apply to the html tag

Comment: @user3550879 You can apply the same principle, just swap the body element for the html element. You can even use it in the <head> of the document so only some style sheets / JS files load on the homepage. You simply swap your normal body / html element for what I've posted above and away you go :-)

Comment: so as in <html class="auto"> underneath <body class... in each section?

Answer (score 0):

On your `index.php` file.
You can use inline styling.

Set your CSS like this:

```
html, body {
  overflow: auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Now, on your `index.php` file your body tag will look like:

```
<body style='overflow: hidden;'>
```

Comment: how can I change the html though since its html, body { ... changing just the body ruins the functionality

Answer (score 0):

Use This code in your header file before body tag:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'index.php' ) ) {
    <style>
   html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   }
   </style>
```

You can also use it for body tag in header file like this:

```
    if ( is_page_template( 'index.php' ) ) {
        <body style='overflow: hidden;'>
    }
```

Comment: problem is the <body> tag (and I assume the html tag) is in the header.php the index.php content is in the index.php